# Why does ubuntu 12.04 freeze?

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, freeze, windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

I dual booted Ubuntu on Windows 8 (Getting the dual boot right alone took 2 tries, thanks to UEFI framework). After the dual boot, Ubuntu started to freeze, mouse won't work, keypad won't work, I had no option but to power cycle it :( ...it's a new system, yet I had to power-cycle it twice before updating and switching to unity 2D mode. Soon after something happened to GRUB and it failed to load, the system would boot straight into Windows 8.

I had to delete the partition and re-install Ubuntu, after re-installing I updated Ubuntu and switched to Unity 2D, but after 8 hours of use, it froze again. This is too much work, I just wanna install my Linux based OS and work with it, not spend every day re-installing it. I also tried searching about this [BUG](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/993187) on the internet. Is there any way around this that is known of or maybe I could try getting 12.10. Does 12.10 freeze regularly as well?

I got my new system only a few weeks back, it has an Intel Core i5 processor and an Intel HD 4000 integrated graphic, I don't see how this could be hardware's fault? I know, my post has lot of useless information but it's been so much work, just to get things work.

I love coding on Ubuntu, I like the nix-like environment but now, I think I might have to give it up if it's gonna need me re-install it every other day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well actually you **SHOULD** update to Ubuntu 12.10 (Not just do an upgrade from 12.04 to 12.10 but actually start from scratch with 12.10 just to be sure). This is because in 12.10, many features found in the Linux kernel for the Intel core i3, i5, i7 and their respective video cards (HD 3000 and 4000) were added. So you will substantially see a huge benefit when you jump to 12.10. I know I did with my i7 and HD 3000.

Basically there is much more support for all Intel Core 2nd and 3rd generations in 12.10. There is also more support for newer motherboards and devices in general.

Also, the performance of the Intel HD 3000 and 4000 is way better than in 12.04.

I also read your BUG link and it started with many users having problem, but the more they moved to a newer version, the less people reported problems, and they even included several solutions to that specific bug. Either way, upgrading to 12.10 will most likely solve your problem and if not, you at least have several new options to try out from that bug report that have worked for several users.

Comment: Why upgrade the whole system if the kernel is the only "problem"?.

Comment: @UriHerrera Ishaan has already tried installing several times, if the kernel is the problem I would not recommend using a custom one, instead, upgrading will most likely solve this issue. Not only the issue he is having but other ones that appear in 12.04 and not in 12.10 in regards to using the Intel HD 3000/4000. So I am recommending this since it will solve him the problems he is having and others as well. Again, I would not recommend using a custom kernel if that would be a solution from experience.

Comment: And why not grab the Default Quantal kernel and install it in Precise?, not the mainline Kernels.

Comment: Because that would involve updating a lot of stuff that depends on that precise kernel version. Remember that for example X.org, drivers and such depend on such changes. Besides Uri, would it not be easier to recommend the user to upgrade than to look for and install specific kernel version from another Ubuntu version. I think it should be left as last option to do what you propose before testing a complete upgrade of the system to ensure there are no more problems at hand.